# Запятая при сравнении

Tags: сравнение, пунктуация

Читаем у Некрасова:

> Как грабли руки тощие, Как спицы ноги
> длинные.

Руки сравниваются с граблями, ноги - со спицами. Тогда почему после *грабли* и *спицы* нет запятых?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В примере, который вы приводите, сравнительный оборот  входит в сказуемое (образует именную часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без сравнительного оборота): Запятая в этом случае не ставится. Ср.: Как ребёнок душою я стал; ''Город как город'', — хладнокровно заметил Базаров. 
См.: Полный академический справочник.

Answer (score 2):

Оборот не выделяется запятыми, если на первый план выступает обстоятельственное значение. В таком случае его  можно заменить наречием или творительным падежом существительного (руки граблями, ноги спицами). Еще одно пояснение (тоже из Розенталя) касается тех случаев, когда оборот тесно связан со сказуемым и образует именную часть сказуемого (руки какие? тощие как грабли)

Comment: Виктор, оборот можно заменить творительным падежом или наречием не когда на первый план выступает обстоятельственное значение, а когда на первый план выступает обстоятельство образа действия. Иначе можно подумать, что при любом обстоятельстве оборот можно заменить творительным падежом или наречием. В данном конкретном случае нет обстоятельственного значения. По крайне мере в данном примере. В более широком контексте может и есть об-во образа действия.